# Cannot read property 'ExpoImageManipulator' of undefined

Tags: react-native, expo

I want to compress image using `expo-image-manipulator`. I followed documentation [Expo-ImageManipulator](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/imagemanipulator/). Everything seems fine but i get "Cannot read property 'ExpoImageManipulator' of undefined". Have you ever faced this error?

```
import { manipulateAsync } from "expo-image-manipulator";

  const manipResult = async (imageUri) =>
      await manipulateAsync(
      imageUri,
      [{ resize: { width: 640, height: 480 } }],
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downgraded version of `expo-image-manipulator`. Now it works.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, i don't have an enough reputation so can't do comment, only answer...
Did you try do their examples with all params for manipulateAsunc?

```
const _rotate90andFlip = async () => {
    const manipResult = await manipulateAsync(
      image.localUri || image.uri, // maybe you don't have this value
      [
        { rotate: 90 },
        { flip: FlipType.Vertical },
      ],
      { compress: 1, format: SaveFormat.PNG } // or need add this
    );
    setImage(manipResult);
  };
```

Comment: Andrii Svirskyi, I get same error(

Comment: I saw that you had created an question on their github, did you try use their examples? With their mock data?

Comment: I have solved it. I just downgraded version. Thank you for answer.

Comment: Great) glad for you)